# celery user permission denied to /bin/celery

Tags: celery, file-permissions, daemon, celeryd

I am trying to daemonize a celery configuration on an aws instance.

Following the [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html), I have:

```
/etc/init.d/celeryd
/etc/default/celerybeat
```

I've created both a celery user and celery group and set permissions like so:

```
sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/log/celery/
sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/run/celery/
sudo chown celery:celery /home/sfree/meampy/bin/celery
```

When I check the file's permissions, it looks good:

```
(meampy)[]$ ls -l /home/sfree/meampy/bin/celery
-rwxrwxrwx 1 celery celery 237 Sep 13 15:15 /home/sfree/meampy/bin/celery
```

But when I run the script:

```
sudo  sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start

...

Starting celeryd...
+ _chuid -f /var/log/celery/beat.log -l INFO --detach --pidfile=/var/run/celery/beat.pid
+ su celery -c '/home/sfree/meampy/bin/celery beat -f /var/log/celery/beat.log -l INFO --detach --pidfile=/var/run/celery/beat.pid'
bash: /home/sfree/meampy/bin/celery: Permission denied
+ exit 0
```

If I run the offending line solo, I get the same error.

`meampy` is the name of my virtualenv. Is the virtualenv the reason I am running into permission problems?

EDIT: the permissions on the virtualenv:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 sfree www-data      24 Sep  1 19:49 meampy -> /usr/local/python/meampy
```

I added the celery user to the `www-data` group, still same error

Comment: does the celery user have access to `/var/run/celery`?

Comment: yes i ran sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/run/celery/. at any rate i solved the problem by using supervisord instead.

Comment: So is `supervisord` running the celery process as the same user you were attempting to another? Any info might help someone else if they encounter the same issue.

Comment: To be honest I don't remember, it was a v long time ago and I no longer have access to the repo. I think, though, that I was either running it anonymously or as some other user I had created.

Answer (score 1):

Because virtualenv meampy is belong to sfree, you should modify your celery config file (/etc/default/celeryd)

set

```
CELERYD_USER="sfree"
CELERYD_GROUP="sfree"
```

and do not forget

```
sudo chown -R sfree:sfree /var/log/celery/
sudo chown -R sfree:sfree /var/run/celery/
```